# Proto3 setting default value to fields?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Does it make sense to set the default value for a field in proto3?

Suppose I have

```
message MyMsg {
  bool some_bool;
}
```

In my java code I have

```
MyMsg instance = MyMsg.newBuilder().setSomeBool(false).build();
sendOffMyMsgOverTheWrite(instance);
```

Is there any difference between the above snippet and the below snippet:

```
MyMsg instance = MyMsg.newBuilder().build(); //not setting someBool explicitly to false.
sendOffMyMsgOverTheWrite(instance);
```

Is there any difference at **all** in `proto3`? I think because all fields are optional by default it should not make a difference in serialization.

Comment: semantically, yes: this shouldn't make a difference - I can't give you a definitive answer on the java API specifically, though; in theory it could know the difference internally in the object model; but you're right: the serialization output should be the same either way **in proto3** (in proto2 this *can* be different, so it really depends on whether the generate code distinguishes between proto2/proto3 here, or whether it shares the same core)